# Hypothesis testing with Neyman–Pearson (finding cutoff quantile of Poisson dist)

Tags: r, self-study, hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution, likelihood-ratio

I am currently trying to solve a problem that should be very easy, yet I am stumped, and help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

***The background of the question is this:***

Q: The number of typing errors in a newspaper can be modeled by a Poisson distribution with some mean $μ$. Each of the $31$ students in a journalism course are allocated at random a past edition of the The Guard newspaper and asked to find the number of typing errors it contains. The total number of errors found by the students is $120$, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i=120$.

It has been hypothesized by the instructor of the course that there are an average of $5$ typing errors in each edition of The Guard. The editor of the newspaper has objected, claiming that the mean is less than $5$ per edition. You want to test this with at $5\%$ significance level.

***Here is where I begin my work***

So I want to test: $H_0:\mu_o=5$ and $H_a:\mu_a<5$.

According to the Neyman Pearson lemma, we can create the most powerful test by looking at the likelihood ratio (LR). I simplified the LR and got the following which I believe is correct, hopefully!

$$LR= e^{-n\mu_a+n\mu_0}(\frac{\mu_a}{\mu_0})^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i}$$

Now looking at the ratio, and the fact that $\mu_a<\mu_0$, we can see that *effectively* our test statistic is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$, and as it increases, we get less comfortable rejecting $H_0$, since it makes our LR smaller.

*Now this is where I am stuck:*

Now I know that to reject $H-0$, I need to find the cut off value where $\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i \le k$ where $k$ is the cutoff value.

So since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$ is our test statistic, we can say that we have $n=31$ independent Poisson distributions which leads our test statistic to have $n\mu_0$ Poisson distribution. I am unsure if what I just did is correct or not, but assuming it is, we next want to find $k$. Using $R$, we have our test statistic model $n\mu_0$ $=$ $31\cdot4=124$ which we can use in $R$.

`qpois(0.05` ( = significance level) `,124)` ( = our new parameter for the mean under H_0) = 106

which is incorrect. Hopefully this clears up the confusion! Thanks so much everyone!!

Comment: Remember the Poisson is discrete, so the quantile function can't return exactly $k:\Pr(\sum Y\leq k)= 0.05$. What it does return is in the manual.

Comment: You should also clarify how your model & hypotheses are describing the problem. Define $H_0$ & $y$ & $n$ properly. If $\sum y$'s the sum of errors over 31 newspapers, & $H_0$ concerns the mean no. errors per paper then how do the two relate?

Comment: Thank you for your help. If qpois is not to be used to find the quantile, then why is it there? My textbook hint says to use ppois but that would give us a probability, what we want is a cutoff point? Sorry, I'm just terribly confused :/

Comment: Why are you using $0.05$ as the argument to `qpois`? Don't you want to use $1-0.05$?

Comment: I have tried $0.95$ as well as $0.05$ and the answer is either $1$ or $0$ respectively. I was using $0.05$ since we want the lower tail quantile.

Comment: You might want to consult the help page and redo the calculation: the correct output of `qpois(1-0.05, 5)` is $9$, not $0$ or $1$. But since you want the left tail, you should be computing `qpois(0.05, 5)-1`. The output is $1$. What's the matter with that? The more important consideration is where your $H_0$ came from: how did that value of $5$ originate? And why are you not looking at the distribution of all $31$ observations, which supplies far more useful information than just their sum?

Comment: Thank you for your help. My apologies as I should have been more specific. $H_0$ came from the question but the question was too long so I tried to keep it concise by just saying that $H_0=5$ is what we want to test. As far as the $31$ observations, it is not up to me, my prof wanted it this way. If I may ask, why did you subtract by 1? You have $qpois(0.05,5,)-1$, why do we need to subtract by $1$? Thanks so much!

Comment: This reads like [routine bookwork](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). How does this question arise?

Comment: Oh as in homework? Yes, it a problem from my textbook, but when I made the question I didn't see the homework tag! Should I restate the whole problem in a new question or completely update this one?

Comment: Hi nicefella -- if you amend your question to include the `self-study` tag and add a little information that gives a sense that you really had a proper attempt (and where precisely, your difficulties arose), I'm confident that will be sufficient. (The alternative is to ask more generic questions that would help you resolve the problem.)

Comment: Okay thanks so much @Glen_b , I will revise the question and add the self study tag, thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from a few oddnesses with notation, you seem to have almost got it sorted out.

This bit is wrong, though:

> Now to find the value of k where we would reject H0 when the total number of observed errors is no greater than k, can we not just use R with the following code:

```
qpois(0.05 = the alpha level,5 = value of null)
```

You need to stick with the observed number of errors across the sample. With 31 people, you won't observe only a few errors. If you try to work with 'number of errors per person' (i.e. you divide the total number of errors by the number of people), it's *no longer a Poisson distribution*, but a scaled Poisson (it takes values that are multiples of $\frac{1}{31}$), and the ignoring the distinction will give you grief. Better to just work with the integer variable, "the total count of errors".

Under the null hypothesis, the distribution of $\sum_i y_i$ has a distribution you can easily work out.

You can then use the inverse cdf, or quantile function (`qpois` in R) to compute the critical value you need for your rejection rule, but take care about what it gives you. If it's not clear to you why you would subtract 1 as whuber suggested, you should use the cdf (`ppois` in R) to compute the *actual significance level* for the rejection rule you propose; that should make it obvious why. (Alternatively, draw a diagram of what's going on, and it should soon become clear.)

Here I've drawn the probability function for the total count of a similar but different problem (one with different numbers):

[image]

The aim is to find the value $C$ which will yield a type-I error rate that is no more than 0.05 (the sum of all the probabilities up to and including it, as suggested by the brace underneath the diagram). If you keep that straight, you should have little trouble working out what's going on

Comment: Hey @Glen_b thanks so much, so I have updated the question quite thoroughly now so hopefully that sheds more light on things. So the distribution of the sum of $y_i$ is important correct? That is what I have tried to do but it still doesn't work. I believe my previous approach was completely wrong! Thanks so much for your guidance!

Comment: nicefella: If the null holds, what is the distribution of the total number of errors for 31 people?

Comment: It is a $n\mu_0$ Poisson distribution I believe (hopefully)!

Comment: Correct. But you actually know both $n$ and $\mu_0$, so you can state it as a number. It's a Poisson with a known mean. Perhaps if you plot that probability function.

Comment: Exactly, so $n=31$ and $\mu_0=4$ thus our new Poisson distribution is $pois(124)$ right? So by that logic, would qpois(significance level=0.05,124 = our new parameter for the mean under H_0) = 106 be the correct value for $k$?

Comment: Also, one more question, my textbook says we can find $k$ by using ppois as well in $R$, but doesn't that give us probabilities, we want a number or a quantile so how could ppois help us? I have looked at the documentation and it is quite vague!

Comment: Where did 4 come from?? Have another look at your post. You can use `ppois` to work out the significance level for any rejection rule, which makes it easy to find the right critical value if you know roughly where to start looking. qpois will tell you where to start looking, but check your actual rejection rate if it's not obvious why it will almost always give you too high an answer.

Comment: My apologies as I have an extremely careless error that has cost me lots of time and I really appreciate your help! $\mu_0=5$ not $4$!! I understand now and diagram you have made is quite useful, I shall make them for every problem I solve now. Oh okay I see the relationship, thank you so much sir, I really appreciate your time!

Comment: Note that in different questions (depending on the alternative), you may need to look in the other tail, or in both tails.

Comment: Ah of course! So in this case, I have calculated that $k=135$, to find the p-value all I need to do is find the area that you have illustrated right? Since that is the area that makes us reject the null? So I'd use ppois(135,155) since $155$ is the our poisson mean

Comment: No, you need to have (up to) 5% in the lower tail. If the alternative was ">5" you'd need (up to) 5% in the upper tail. If the alternative was "$\neq$5" you'd need (up to) 5% in total between the two tails. You have the first kind of problem. You need to compute a value for $C$ which has no more than 5% of the probability at or below it. (Sorry I keep using $C$ instead of the $k$ in your question -- simple lack of attention to your notation on my part.)

Comment: If the null is true, what's the probability that you will obtain a statistic $\leq$ 135?

Comment: Is that not the same thing as asking for the p-value under 135? That would just be ppois(135,155)= 0.05622526.

Comment: I completely understand what you wrote about the 5% being split up or not depending on our alternative hypothesis but I am very shaky on these sorts of problems even though I have studied it so much :/

Comment: Okay, so if you know that $P(\sum Y_i<135|H_0)=0.0562..$, you know $k$ isn't 135.

Comment: Really? Why is that because my textbook gives answers for every other problem and it seems like $k=135$. I'm probably in the wrong with my answer above though

Comment: The usual convention is not to exceed the nominal $\alpha$ (though there's nothing wrong in practice with explicitly choosing $\alpha=0.0562$). How does your textbook define 'significance level'? Does it give a convention when the desired significance level is unattainable (as here)?

Comment: Ah I see, my book says the following: "The probability over repeated samples of a Type I error is the significance level, often denoted by $\alpha$". I think since we have a discrete R.V. then it is difficult to get exactly $0.05$ as $\alpha$.

Comment: Correct. Does it suggest any solution to that problem of not being able to have exactly 0.05 when the distribution of the test statistic is not continuous?

Comment: No, it just says if the R.V. is not continuous, it is "difficult". I have a much, much easier time with continuous R.V.s

Comment: Okay, no problem, so it doesn't give a convention. If you do something like say "I choose a critical value of k=135 because it gives close to 5% significance", well, that's fine. (It's not the most common convention, but there's nothing special about the convention, as long as you're explicit about what you do when you can't get the significance level you want. If you aren't explicit, people may assume you're following that convention.)

Comment: Ah, I understand, I'll be sure to mention it on my work as well as exams!